# How to do a list comprehension to a relation?

Tags: list-comprehension, rascal

In my code I have the following two methods:

```
public void AllDivisors(int max) {
     lrel[int,list[int]] div = [ <i,d> | int i <- [0 .. max], list[int] d <- GetDivisors(i)];
     println("<div>");
}

public list[int] GetDivisors(int n) {
      return [ p | p <- [1..n], n % p == 0];
}
```

The second one (GetDivisors) gives the list of divisors for `n` and returns those as a `list[int]`. Next I want to map those on the values of `n` using a `lrel` in the first method (AllDivisors). I was trying to get this done in one go using a list comprehension, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
rascal>GetDivisors(10);
list[int]: [1,2,5]

rascal>AllDivisors(10);
|project://Sevo/src/NumberEx.rsc|(189,1,<8,85>,<8,86>): Expected int, but    got list[int]
Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/UnexpectedType/UnexpectedType.html|
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out where Rascal is expecting an `int` but getting a `list[int]`. I suppose it's in `d <- GetDivisors(i)`. How can I generate the correct tuples in my list-comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in:

```
list[int] d <- GetDivisors(i)
```

when you iterate over the results of `GetDivisors` you are getting `int`'s not, `list[int]`'s. So changing that to `int d`, or just `d` (type inference) should be good enough.

you could also do this:

```
lrel[int,list[int]] div = [ <i,d> | int i <- [0 .. max], list[int] d := GetDivisors(i)];
```

This binds the `d` variable to the result of `GetDivisors`

But for this case I would write it as follows:

```
div = [ <i, GetDivisors(i)> | i <- [0..max]];
```

Comment: That last expression is spot on!

Answer (score 4):

The root of your problem is `list[int] d <- GetDivisors(i)`. Since `GetDivisors` returns `list[int]` its elements are of type `int`.

So the first fix is: `int d <- GetDivisors(i)`.

But now you will also have to fix the type of `div` into `lrel[int,int] div`.

The complete example then becomes:

```
public void AllDivisors(int max) {

    lrel[int,int] div = [ <i,d> | int i <- [0 .. max], int d <- GetDivisors(i)];
    println("<div>"); }

 public list[int] GetDivisors(int n) {
    return [ p | p <- [1..n], n % p == 0]; }
```

A note on style: we usually let function names start with a lower case letter.

Comment: I really wanted the lrel to have type [int, list[int]] though. Tuples of int and list[int]. And for you remark on style: I'll try to do better :). I spend most of  my days in C#, so those conventions come naturally.